# Xunit.TestFrameworkAttribute not picking up custom XUnitTestFramework from different assembly

Tags: .net, .net-core, xunit

I want to reuse this class `CustomTestFramework : XunitTestFramework` across several test projects to avoid duplicating some simple setup code.

The problem I ran across is that the following setup doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why:

```
// In some common library, full type is TestLibrary.CustomTestFramework
CustomTestFramework : XunitTestFramework { ... }

// In one of my test projects
[assembly: Xunit.TestFramework("TestLibrary.CustomTestFramework", "TestProject")]
```

This will work if I move `CustomTestFramework` in my test project, but I'd like to avoid having to add a new class in each test project.

Comment: Is the `TestProject` library dll present in the build directory of the test project?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, under `TestProject/bin/Debug/net6.0` I have two dll's (beside the usual ones) - `TestProject.dll` and `TestLibrary.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this answer just in case another noob like me stumbles upon this, the right way is this:

`[assembly: Xunit.TestFramework("TestLibrary.CustomTestFramework", "TestLibrary")]`

The second parameter is obviously the assembly where we find `CustomTestFramework`, not the one where we want to use it.